# .NET FormsAuthentication issue with load balanced servers running IIS 7 and using cookies

Tags: .net, cookies, iis-7, forms-authentication, load-balancing

I have a pair of load balanced web servers running a .NET 3.5 / MVC 2 application.  We are using Forms Authentication with cookies.

When a user is kicked off to the second server,  `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always comes back as `false`, and so the user is signed out.

The other interesting tidbit is that the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie is still being passed from the browser, can still be seen in the request headers, but **no longer exists** in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies`.  I've set the auth cookie `HttpOnly` and `Secure` to `true`.

I've checked that both web servers are using the same exact machine keys as set in their web.config files.

Comment: How is your session information stored?